# Python merge three lines of .split() into one line?

Tags: python, split

I have this code where I'm hoping the three split commands can be combined into a single line but I can't figure out how:

```
from __future__ import print_function       # Must be first import
import subprocess32 as sp

def get_mouse_coordinates():
    ''' Get mouse co-ordinates with xdotool:
            $ xdotool getmouselocation
            x:4490 y:1920 screen:0 window:65011722
    '''
    command_line_list = ['xdotool', 'getmouselocation']

    pipe = sp.Popen(command_line_list, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
    text, err = pipe.communicate()              # This performs .wait() too

    print("returncode of subprocess:",pipe.returncode)

    if text:
        x, y, z = text.split(' ',2)             # Grab 'x:9999' 'y:9999' 'junk'
        x_ret = x.split(':')[1]                 # Grab right of 'x:9999'
        y_ret = y.split(':')[1]                 # Grab right of 'y:9999'

        print("standard output of subprocess:")
        print(text,'x-offset:',x_ret,'y-offset:',y_ret)
        return x_ret, y_ret

    if err:
        print("standard error of subprocess:")
        print(err)
        return 100, 100
```

Probably blatantly obvious but these are the three lines of code:

```
x, y, z = text.split(' ',2)             # Grab 'x:9999' 'y:9999' 'junk'
x_ret = x.split(':')[1]                 # Grab right of 'x:9999'
y_ret = y.split(':')[1]                 # Grab right of 'y:9999'
```

If you are curious, output in terminal:

```
returncode of subprocess: 0
standard output of subprocess:
x:3400 y:558 screen:0 window:23073340
 x-offset: 3400 y-offset: 558
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with those 3 splits. You could also use a regex, if you think that is better.

Comment: What do you mean by "combine"? Are you talking about the *coding style*, or about the *output*? If you're talking about the output, then what exactly is different between the output you showed, and the output you *want*? If you're talking about the coding style, then why don't you like the code you have?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Sorry I wasn't clear. I want to merge the three lines of code into one. The output is only for debugging and in the final version will be commented out or deleted.

Comment: Oh, I misread; you have the second two lines *depending on* the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @zvone mentioned, one way to do this is with regex. Essentially you are just trying to pull out the numbers so the pattern is quite simple:

```
    import re
    
    x, y, screen, window = re.findall("[0-9]+", text)
```

Note if the numbers were able to be negative you would need a slightly longer pattern (but it seems that in your case, they won't be):

```
    import re
    
    x, y, screen, window = re.findall("[-+]?[0-9]+", text)
```

Documentation for the regex module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

You could also use a list comprehension:

```
    x, y, screen, window = [tok.split(":")[1] for tok in text.split(" ")]
```